# Перенес программу на другую винду, начали вылетать ошибки подключения к локальной базе данный

Tags: c#, sql, база-данных

`System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: "An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file D:\Microsoft VS Code\****\****\Database.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share."`
Вот одна из ошибок вылетела с этим кодом

```
SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            connect.ConnectionString =
            @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;" +
            @"AttachDbFilename=D:\Microsoft VS Code\RKSI_bot\RKSI_bot\Database.mdf;" +
            @"Integrated Security = True;" +
            @"Connect Timeout = 30;";

            cmd.Connection = connect;

            connect.Open();
```

Comment: а БД перенесли на другую винду?

Comment: @tym32167 у меня все было на диске D, винда на диске C, т.е диск Д вообще не трогал, и не форматировал, только диск С

Comment: не важно, какие диски вы трогали. Вы пытаетесь подключться к `(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;"` - а он у вас есть вообще?

Comment: @tym32167 Хороший вопрос, я вообще незнаю что это

Comment: [SQL Server Express LocalDB](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver15) - это версия SQL Server для разработчиков. Она обычно идет вместе со вижуал студией как один из компонентов.

Comment: @tym32167 наверное её и нету, если нету, то вижуал студио мне нужно переустанавливать, или есть нугет пакет?

Comment: Я вам ссылку дал, там написано как установить

Comment: @tym32167 Извиняюсь, понял спасибо